# Pycharm ModuleNotFoundError Twilio Package

Tags: python, pycharm, twilio, whatsapp

I have already looked around the website and nothing has solved my problem.
I am trying to import scipy,numpy,sympy and twilio and I always get the ModuleNotFoundError, even though all the packages are on my site-packages folder and they are running on the same version of python (3.7 in this case). 
[image]

Comment: try to access it via konsole first and see if your pycharm python interpretter set to venv or not

Comment: I set it to venv and now I get the same error with this path:/Users/sergioruiz/PycharmProject/AutomationPractice/venv/lib/python3.7/OrganizeMe/Whatsapp.py

Comment: you use pycharm's package installer? or you installed it via console?

Comment: I normally use Pycharm's but I have also tried it in the console and it said Requirement satisfied.

Comment: Try making a new venv and using that